# What is the correct way to use any(), all(), etc., with the dplyr::filter() + dplyr::across() combination?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, any, across

Say I have the following `data.frame` `df`:

```
#         col1        col2       col3 othercol1 othercol11
# 1      Hello WHAT_hello2      Hello        10          3
# 2 WHAT_hello  WHAT_hello WHAT_hello         1          2
# 3      Hello       Hello      Hello         9          1
```

I would like to process the `data.frame` to only retain those rows that contain the prefix `WHAT_` in at least one of `col1`, `col2`, or `col3`.

Now I know that I can do this easily with `|`, but I was trying to achieve this using `dplyr::across` and `tidyselect::matches` along with `base::any` and `stringr::str_detect` to point `dplyr::filter` at the right columns. But this doesn't seem to work, even when used in conjunction with `dplyr::rowwise`.

So what is the correct way to go about this here? What am I doing wrong?

I would like to use `across` + `any` primarily because I might not necessarily in advance know how many of these columns I'd have in the actual dataset.

Here's my example (data + code) below:

```
#Libraries.
library(base)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyselect)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)



#Toy data.
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("Hello", "WHAT_hello", "Hello"), 
                 col2 = c("WHAT_hello2", "WHAT_hello", "Hello"), 
                 col3 = c("Hello", "WHAT_hello", "Hello"),
                 othercol1 = sample(1:10, 3), 
                 othercol11 = sample(1:10, 3), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



#Works.
df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(col1, "^WHAT_") | str_detect(col2, "^WHAT_") | str_detect(col3, "^WHAT_"))

#Output.
# col1        col2       col3 othercol1 othercol11
# 1      Hello WHAT_hello2      Hello         1          2
# 2 WHAT_hello  WHAT_hello WHAT_hello         5          4


#Works (incorrectly).
df %>% 
  filter(
    across(.cols = matches("^col"), 
           .fns = ~ any(str_detect(.x, "^WHAT")) )
  )

#Output.
# col1        col2       col3 othercol1 othercol11
# 1      Hello WHAT_hello2      Hello         1          2
# 2 WHAT_hello  WHAT_hello WHAT_hello         5          4
# 3      Hello       Hello      Hello         4          7



#Works (incorrectly) also.
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(
    across(.cols = matches("^col"), 
           .fns = ~ any(str_detect(.x, "^WHAT")) )
  )

#Output.
#   col1       col2       col3       othercol1 othercol11
#   <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          <int>      <int>
# 1 WHAT_hello WHAT_hello WHAT_hello         5          4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For functions applying to rows rather than columns you can use `c_across` with `rowwise`:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(any(str_detect(c_across(matches('^col')), '^WHAT')))

# # A tibble: 2 x 5
# # Rowwise: 
#   col1       col2        col3       othercol1 othercol11
#   <chr>      <chr>       <chr>          <int>      <int>
# 1 Hello      WHAT_hello2 Hello              9          7
# 2 WHAT_hello WHAT_hello  WHAT_hello         3         10
```

Or, using `across` with `rowSums`:

```
row_lgl <- 
  df %>% 
    transmute(across(.cols = matches("^col"), .fns = ~ str_detect(.x, "^WHAT"))) %>% 
    rowSums %>% 
    '>'(0)
           
df %>% 
  filter(row_lgl)
#         col1        col2       col3 othercol1 othercol11
# 1      Hello WHAT_hello2      Hello         9          7
# 2 WHAT_hello  WHAT_hello WHAT_hello         3         10
```

Answer (score 1):

using `base`

```r
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("Hello", "WHAT_hello", "Hello"), 
                 col2 = c("WHAT_hello2", "WHAT_hello", "Hello"), 
                 col3 = c("Hello", "WHAT_hello", "Hello"),
                 othercol1 = sample(1:10, 3), 
                 othercol11 = sample(1:10, 3), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df 
#>         col1        col2       col3 othercol1 othercol11
#> 1      Hello WHAT_hello2      Hello         1          9
#> 2 WHAT_hello  WHAT_hello WHAT_hello         3          2
#> 3      Hello       Hello      Hello         4          8

df[apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(grepl(pattern = "^WHAT_", x = x))) != 0, ]
#>         col1        col2       col3 othercol1 othercol11
#> 1      Hello WHAT_hello2      Hello         1          9
#> 2 WHAT_hello  WHAT_hello WHAT_hello         3          2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

using `tidyverse`

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("Hello", "WHAT_hello", "Hello"), 
                 col2 = c("WHAT_hello2", "WHAT_hello", "Hello"), 
                 col3 = c("Hello", "WHAT_hello", "Hello"),
                 othercol1 = sample(1:10, 3), 
                 othercol11 = sample(1:10, 3), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df %>% 
  filter(rowSums(across(.cols = where(is.character), .fns = ~ str_detect(.x, "^WHAT"))) != 0)
#>         col1        col2       col3 othercol1 othercol11
#> 1      Hello WHAT_hello2      Hello         1          3
#> 2 WHAT_hello  WHAT_hello WHAT_hello         7          4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I really like both solutions presented here, very innovative, especially the `base` one!! I am accepting @IceCreamToucan 's answer as that addresses the question in my OP quite directly (i.e., how to use `filter` and `across` with `any`/`all` properly).